# How can i split a string by whitespace and underscore?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can get split by underscore working, but not with 2 delimiters (in this case underscore and whitespace).

Example:

`mystring = Tom Dough__________8.5 7.5 9.5`

What i want :

`['Tom', 'Dough', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '8.5', '7.5', '9.5']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `split` function in the `re` package:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystring = "Tom Dough__________8.5 7.5 9.5"
>>> re.split(' |_', mystring)
['Tom', 'Dough', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '8.5', '7.5', '9.5']
```

Comment: what i forgot to mention was that i have multiple of these lines,

i used [i.split('_') for i in students] to split underscores where students is the list containing multiple lines of students and their grades.

so your answer will give me an error

Comment: Could you give a full example of your data in that case?

Comment: I already found my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer was very useful for me, thank you grahamlyons